Работа asyncio в python
Хочу глубже понять как устроена асинхронность в python. Объясните, как задача понимает, что её работа закончена и всё это выполняется в одном потоке. Хочу понять максимально подробно как всё устроено на низком уровне

С задачей то все просто, функция ее представляющая завершилась, вернула управление - вот и задача считается завершенной, остается только запись с результатом. Со вторым сложнее, тут лекция на час нужна. Начиная с работы связки процессор-память с перфирийными устройствами. После того как поняли, что такое внешний ввод-вывод для процессора, переходим к функции ядер ОС и языка C select (poll/epoll) https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=select&category=2&russian=0  а далее переходим уже в питон, где крутится цикл, в середине которого та select ждет всех дескрипторов что задачи надобавляли

А задачи это по сути просто таблица с записями о них, с состоянием на чем они остановились. Что бы когда select скажет, что дескриптор можно читать/писать переключиться на их стек и продолжить выполнение с прерванного места

@Mike благодарю, буду изучать

тут главное уяснить, что пока что то процессор вычисляет, перекладывает сам в в памяти, то асинхронности быть не может, разве что сам процесс вызовет asyncio.sleep сообщив тем самым главному циклу, что его сейчас можно положить в сторонку и отдать поток процессора другим. Асинхронность начинается там, когда понадобилось получить или передать данные куда то наружу, вне оперативной памяти: диск, сеть, сокет с соседним процессом, клава, и т.п. И вот тут как раз появляется лазейка, просто отложить в сторонку запись о этой задаче с ее стеком, пока внешнее устройство данные не отдаст

Если прям всерьёз «на низком уровне», то это уже даже не про питон, а скорее про устройство процессора и операционной системы читать. Я вот тут недавно читал книжку Asynchronous Programming in Rust — несмотря на Rust в названии, первая половина книжки рассказывает про фундаменталку, не зависящую от языка программирования (прерывания, потоки, гринтреды / файберы, футуры / промисы, epoll, вот это вот всё)

@andreymal спасибо, я вот читал Asyncio и конкурентное программирование на Python Мэтью Фаулера, но там как-то поверхностно по этой теме прошлись Не понимал почему на задачах CPU-bound async не работает, с потоками всё ясно было что там GIL не позволяет. Хочется  ведь не просто писать код, а понимать как это работает на низах.

@Leinther ну тут наверно кратко можно ответить — потому что, пока CPU-bound задача работает, она не возвращает управление в event loop, а значит тот не имеет возможности запускать другие задачи, и в итоге они простаивают неизвестно сколько в ожидании пока CPU-bound задача наконец закончит свою работу и передаст управление в event loop

Если коротко, то при попании на слово await или в конце async функции управление передается на loop, который смотрит не разблокировался ли какой-то сокет, разблокирует зависимые от него асинхронные таски и запускает следующий не заблокированный асинхронный кусок.

Спасибо за ответ, буду дальше разбираться

Без "машины состояний" async/await мне кажется нельзя объяснять )
